# How does Scala compiler handle unused variable values?

Tags: performance, scala, memory, apache-spark

Using Scala and Spark, I have the following construction:

```
val rdd1: RDD[String] = ...
val rdd2: RDD[(String, Any)] = ...

val rdd1pairs = rdd1.map(s => (s, s))
val result = rdd2.join(rdd1pairs)
              .map { case (_: String, (e: Any, _)) => e }
```

The purpose of mapping `rdd1` into a `PairRDD` is the join with `rdd2` in the subsequent step. However, I am actually only interested in the values of `rdd2`, hence the mapping step in the last line which omits the keys. Actually, this is an intersection between `rdd2` and `rdd1` performed with Spark's `join()` for efficiency reasons.

My question refers to the keys of `rdd1pairs`: they are created for syntactical reasons only (to allow the join) in the first map step and are later discarded without any usage. How does the compiler handle this? Does it matter in terms of memory consumption whether I use the String `s` (as shown in the example)? Should I replace it by `null` or `0` to save a little memory? Does the compiler actually create and store these objects (references) or does it notice that they are never used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is what the Spark driver will do that influences the outcome rather than the compiler, I think. Whether or not Spark can optimise its execution pipeline in order to avoid creating the redundant duplication of `s`. I'm not sure but I think Spark will create the `rdd1pairs`, in memory.

Instead of mapping to `(String, String)` you could use `(String, Unit)`:

```
rdd1.map(s => (s,()))
```

What you're doing is basically a filter of `rdd2` based on `rdd1`. If rdd1 is significantly smaller than rdd2, another method would be to represent the data of `rdd1` as a broadcast variable rather than an RDD, and simply filter `rdd2`. This avoids any shuffling or reduce phase, so may be quicker, but will only work if the data of `rdd1` is small enough to fit on each node.

EDIT:

Considering how using Unit rather than String saves space, consider the following examples:

```
object size extends App {

  (1 to 1000000).map(i => ("foo"+i, ()))
  val input = readLine("prompt> ")
}
```

and

```
object size extends App {

  (1 to 1000000).map(i => ("foo"+i, "foo"+i))
  val input = readLine("prompt> ")
}
```

Using the `jstat` command as described in this question [How to check heap usage of a running JVM from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464770/can-i-check-heap-usage-of-a-running-jvm-from-the-commandline) the first version uses significantly less heap than the latter.

Edit 2:

`Unit` is effectively a singleton object with no contents, so logically, it should not require any serialization. The fact that the type definition contains `Unit` tells you all you need to be able to deserialize a structure which has a field of type Unit.

Spark uses Java Serialization by default. Consider the following:

```
object Main extends App {

  import java.io.{ObjectOutputStream, FileOutputStream}

  case class Foo (a: String, b:String)
  case class Bar (a: String, b:String, c: Unit)

  val str = "abcdef"
  val foo = Foo("abcdef", "xyz")
  val bar = Bar("abcdef", "xyz", ())

  val fos = new FileOutputStream( "foo.obj" )
  val fo = new ObjectOutputStream( fos )
  val bos = new FileOutputStream( "bar.obj" )
  val bo = new ObjectOutputStream( bos )
  fo writeObject foo
  bo writeObject bar
}
```

The two files are of identical size:

```
�� sr Main$Foo3�,�z \ L at Ljava/lang/String;L bq ~ xpt abcdeft xyz
```

and

```
�� sr Main$Bar+a!N��b L at Ljava/lang/String;L bq ~ xpt abcdeft xyz
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks. However, I am still not sure how storing references to Unit saves a significant amount of memory compared to the original string variant. Does it?

Comment: Have extended my answer to cover that topic

Comment: But in the original question no new Strings are created. A reference to a String is the same size as a reference to `()`.

Comment: It's hard to know what Spark is doing under the hood (well, as hard as a detailed reading of the source) but the join will involve a shuffle phase, requiring the data to be serialized, and at that point I'd expect the two references to become two separate serialized strings.

Comment: So how does it serialize Unit values? It certainly requires some (abstract) sort of serialization for that purpose in case the value actually is needed in a later stage.

Comment: Does Spark care that it's working with a tuple, or is it just handling an object like any other? If the pair created by `s => (s, s)` is simply serialized, then both elements of the tuple will point to the same serialized object. If Spark knows that this is a pair and handles both elements separately, you could be right.